# Spring boot application shut down after application run

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-initializr

I try to create Spring boot application using spring initializer. I just created new app using dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

but when ever I try to start the application It just shut down. I have created controller and also follow all the solution like: changing port or removing tomcat from .m2 folder but nothing works.
these are my logs

```
2021-04-30 02:50:10,845 INFO  [main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2021-04-30 02:50:12,067 INFO  [main] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-04-30 02:50:12,087 INFO  [main] org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean: Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-30 02:50:12,914 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger: Started WebApplication in 7.549 seconds (JVM running for 8.848)
2021-04-30 02:50:13,025 INFO  [SpringContextShutdownHook] org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean: Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-30 02:50:13,027 INFO  [SpringContextShutdownHook] org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl: HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2021-04-30 02:50:13,037 INFO  [SpringContextShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-04-30 02:50:13,045 INFO  [SpringContextShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If any one have idea whats going wrong.
I am using spring boot 2.4.5 version.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Comment: Please show your application main() and database-related application properties

Answer (score 2):

It seems tomcat embedded jar is not included in the dependencies/jar. It should have pulled transitively since "spring-boot-starter-web" dependency already defined. But somehow it is excluded.

Try executing "mvn dependency:tree" and check whether the tomcat dependencies exist and in "compile" scope

Comment: Faces the same problem

Answer (score 0):

1. clean you project
2. Restart your IDE

It solved my issue 100%